# How to print a particular select statement three times in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is the code

```
 declare
 a integer;
 begin
  select to_char(to_date('1/1/2017 ','mm/dd/yyyy') + level -1) into a from dual 
   connect by level <=365;
   for a in 1..3 loop
  dbms_output.put_line(a);
  end loop;
 end;
```

Error occurring is exact fetch requested more no of rows
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get multiple value in a scaler variable.

Try this:

```
begin
    for i in (select to_char(to_date('1/1/2017 ','mm/dd/yyyy') + level -1) col
                    from dual 
                    connect by level <=365) loop
        for j in 1..3 loop
            dbms_output.put_line(i.col);
        end loop;
    end loop;
end; 
/
```

Answer (score 0):

1st of all, please be aware about the fact that you declared the "a" variable as integer but then you assign a varchar2 to it.
2nd, I was testing your code and it seems that there is a problem with `level <= 365`.
I changed it into `level = 365` and it seemed to return the expected result.

```
declare
 a integer;
 begin
  select to_char(to_date('1/1/2017 ','mm/dd/yyyy') + level -1) into a from dual 
  -- connect by level <= 365;
  connect by level = 365;
   for a in 1..3 loop
  dbms_output.put_line(a);
  end loop;
 end;
```